# Django docs: resolve() code sample

Tags: django, django-views

I'm confused about the code example at the end of the [resolve documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/urls/#django.core.urlresolvers.resolve) ("test whether a view would raise a Http404 error before redirecting to it"). Could someone provide explanation about this code -what it's doing and how it works? I haven't a clue what's going on.

For example, why would you need to call a view to test if it throws a 404, when `resolve` itself can throw `Resolver404`? When the code calls the view function, it gives it the request via a keyword argument but with other arguments before that. But shouldn't a view get `request` as its first argument? Why is the referer header being used?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Resolver404` is only thrown if the path doesn't resolve to a URL/View function.

The view function itself can still raise a 404 depending on input parameters, like a bad ID.

Theres 2 issues:

- Successfully resolving a regex URL match `'^/(?P<foo>\d+)\d/$'`
- Making sure that the view function with parameter `foo` doesn't raise a 404.

You're right that with the example, `request` should be the first argument. If there are any url `*args` (unnamed regexp matches), request would be added twice since it's typically the first argument. Perhaps a bug in the example?

Comment: Could you comment on why the referer header is being used?